# My ISP does not support ASP.NET MVC. Can I still use some of it anyway?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My ISP doesn't have ASP.NET MVC installed on their servers yet, although they do have .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 so they do have the new routing engine.

It occurs to me that, if I create a model using Linq to SQL, it's possible to expose parts of the model as properties in the code behind.  I could then render them in the web page (my "view") in the usual MVC way:

```
<%= myModel.MyField %>
```

I realize that I don't have Html Helpers (or maybe I do, if I copy the MVC dll to my website directory?), but I can live with that.  I don't have controllers either, but I can simulate one in the Page_Load event of the CodeBehind.

Are there problems with this that I am not aware of?  Have you tried something like this, and how did it work out for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can still use ASP.NET MVC. Read this: [Haacked - Bin Deploying ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Add the MVC dlls to your bin directory. We don't install ASP.Net MVC on production servers